# can i apply gabor filter to tensorflow like code below for CNN Tensorflow python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, opencv, gabor-filter, python

i'm trying to use gabor filter for my tensorflow image classification. i'm getting this value error when trying to run it.

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

```
num_classes = len(class_names)

# Create a 3x3 Gabor filter
params = {'ksize':(32, 32), 'sigma':3.0, 'theta': 1*np.pi/2, 'lambd':1*np.pi /4, 'gamma':0.3}
filters = cv2.getGaborKernel(**params)
# make the filter to have 4 dimensions.
filters = tf.expand_dims(filters, 2)
filters = tf.expand_dims(filters, 3)

# Apply the filter on `image`
#answer = tf.conv2d(image, filter, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size = (32,32), strides = (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (3, 3), strides = (1, 1)),
  layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size = (32,32), strides = (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size= (3, 3), strides = (1, 1)),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])
```